# How to use NSRange or NSMax X with NSRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

How do I go about making boundaries on drawing an NSMakeRect when my x and y coordinates are equal to the mouse coordinates.  I do not want my NSRect to be drawn past a certain coordiante

```
NSMakeRect(mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y, 50, 50);
```

Do I create a range or max x and y values and if so how do i incorporate it into my MakeRect?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do? Do you want a rectangle to follow the mouse, but to be constrained inside some larger rectangle? Or something else?

Comment: yes exactly that! I could just do subtraction but I'd prefer to have boundaries set from the larger rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building 64-bit, then `NSRect` is `typedef`ed to be `CGRect`. You can do the following:

```
CGRect oldRect; // This is the rectangle's previous position saved somewhere
CGRect newRect = NSMakeRect (mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y, 50, 50);
if (CGRectContainsRect (constrainingRect, newRect))
{
    oldRect = newRect;
}
```

So you construct the new rectangle, see if it's contained in the larger bounding rectangle, and if so, replace the old one with the new one. Otherwise, use the old one again.

Comment: Why not just use `NSContainsRect()`?